# Singular points of Steiner surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification

> Find the singular points in $\mathbb{P}^{3}$ of the Steiner surface
>
> $$V(X_{2}^{2} X_{3}^{2} + X_{1}^{2}X_{3}^{2} + X_{1}^{2}X_{2}^{2} - X_{0}X_{1}X_{2}X_{3}).$$

As I understand it, we have to solve $\frac{\partial f}{\partial X_i} = 0$. So we have $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial X_0} = -X_1 X_2 X_3,$$ $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial X_1} = 2X_1 X_{3}^{2} + 2X_1 X_{2}^{2} - X_0 X_2 X_3,$$ $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial X_2} = 2 X_2 X_{3}^{2} + 2X_{1}^{2} X_{2} - X_0 X_1 X_3,$$  $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial X_3} = 2X_{2}^{2} X_{3} + 2X_{1}^{2} X_3 - X_0 X_1 X_2.$$

Setting all of them equal to zero yields $P = (a : 0 : 0 : b)$ or $P = (a : b : 0 : 0)$ or $P = (a : 0 : b : 0)$, where $a, b$ are not both zero.

Is my solution correct?

Is there perhaps a more methodological way of solving this? The way I solved it was to play around with the given equations and see which points will satisfy the conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can exploit the symmetry of the defining equation in the variables with positive index. The first equation says that at least one of $X_1,X_2,X_3$ is zero. Suppose it's $X_1$ - then the other equations reduce to $-X_0X_2X_3$, $2X_2X_3^2$, and $2X_2^2X_3$, which implies one of $X_2$ and $X_3$ must be zero (assuming we're not in characteristic 2 - in characteristic 2, we need to examine the original equation after setting $X_1,X_0=0$ to reach the same conclusion). So the singular locus is the union of $V(X_i,X_j)$ for $i,j\in\{1,2,3\}$ distinct.

Comment: We always assumed a ground field $k$ together with an algebraically closed field extension $K$ where we looked at ideals of $k[X_1, \ldots, X_n]$ but we looked at their varieties in affine or projective space over $K$. Does this tell us something about the characteristic? I'm a bit confused on how to interpret the singular locus. The singular locus is defined as the set of all singular points of $V$. So in your notation this gives us then precisely the points I listed? I.e. points in $\mathbb{P}^{3}$ where two different coordinates are zero?

Comment: @gaith To your first point: the characteristic is the additive order of $1$ in the field and nothing you've said specifies it. The reason we need to consider it here is because if the characteristic is 2, then $2=0$ and the step after setting $X_1=0$ needs a little more work. The point of this post was explaining how to do this in a "more methodical way" as per your question.